# OpenGL error when run rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, opengl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

After I successfully install ros on my PC. I try to run rviz, but come cross an error as follows

```
rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1409663641.718819061]: rviz version 1.11.3
[ INFO] [1409663641.718874433]: compiled against OGRE version 1.8.1 (Byatis)
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
[ INFO] [1409663641.808060686]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1409663641.808351168]: OpenGl version: 1.4 (GLSL 0).
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Your graphics driver does not support OpenGL 2.1. Please enable software rendering before running RViz (e.g. type 'export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1').
```

Is there any solution about this? Thank you.

Best Regards!

Frank

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191680/opengl-error-when-run-rviz/) by [Frank](https://answers.ros.org/users/20119/frank/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yincanben](https://answers.ros.org/users/20734/yincanben/) on 2014-12-25**:
Have you solve this problem?I met the same problem,Can you share how to solve it?

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-10-16**:
Hi, did anyone solved this ?, I just have this error after I installed various graphics and CUDA drivers to get some 3D cameras working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the exception message, it looks like your graphics driver does not support OpenGL 2.1.

If your graphics card does not support hardware acceleration try the following (rviz might run excruciatingly slow, but at least it should run) :

```
$> export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1
$> rosrun rviz rviz
```

If you are certain that your graphics card does support hardware acceleration, make sure that you have installed the adequate driver (proprietary driver?)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on 2015-01-22**:
Hi, I'm running into the exact same problem as the original post (my OpenGL version is also 1.4) but exporting LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 does not fix the problem. I'll run the two lines you mention and the exact same error will occur. Is there anything else to test for/try as a fix?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-22**:
That env variable appears to be a mesa specific thing, people using different drivers may not get the desired affect: http://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html

**Comment by [Eric Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/4619/eric-schneider/) on 2015-01-22**:
Hm. In that case I don't know how to fix the problem. I'll try to figure out which drivers I'm using. Thanks.